# Virtualbox broke my android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox, hyper-v, hypervisor

Installed Virtual Box, emulator stopped working. After doing some research, my guess is that it broke my Hyper-V somehow. It says:

*Unable to start the emulator
The emulator is unable to start because the hypervisor is not running. The likely cause is that hardware-assisted virtualization is enabled.
Check your computer's BIOS to ensure that hardware-assisted virtualization and hardware-assisted data execution protection features are enable.*

I did that. Everything is set as they should be. I uninstalled Virtualbox, including its drivers, following this guide: https://dottech.org/101997/how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-drivers-on-windows/

Still no work. Can somebody please share a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! I got it working! Finally! Here's how I fixed my problem:

**1.** Run cmd as administrator.

**2.** Type in: bcdedit

**3.** At the end, there's a thing that says hypervisorlaunchtype. If it says 'Off', go to the next step.

**4.** Type in: bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype auto

**5.** Restart your computer.